# Syslink form virtualbox shared folder

Tags: mount, virtualbox

I have a ubuntu 14.04 server guest os with ubuntu 14.04 host os. My virtualbox version is 4.3.10. I mount my shared folder to /media/sf_Share in guest. I make a folder in this shared folder and make syslink to /home/ubuntu/ with the following command.

```
ln -sf sf_Share/test /home/ubuntu
```

I can create syslink but can't access to the syslink directory. Actually I want to place this syslink to openerp addon folder and make it able to read from openerp. But it doesn't work.
And I make a folder in openerp addon and make syslink to /media/sf_Share/. It work but this folder can't access from host OS.

I also tried to mount the shared folder directly to my desired directory but I got only Protocol error. I tried with this command.

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 Share /home/ubuntu/Share
```

Already installed virtualbox guest addition in my guest os. I can't find no more solution.

Please help me.

Comment: Finally I got it. "ln" command need to add entire path of directory.

    ln -sf /media/sf_Share/test /home/ubuntu/test

Answer (score 0):

Guest Additions itself may have been causing an additional uninvited issue you were unaware of.

The ticket for the issue can be found here https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12879 and has been resolved in **Guest Additions 4.3.12**

**Guest Additions 4.3.10** has an incorrect symlink for which the workaround is to create a new symlink:

`sudo ln -s /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-4.3.10/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions`

Once the symlink is in place you can use the Virtualbox GUI > Settings > Shared Folders to create a shared_folder_name with read or read/write permissions and check automount if desired.

then in the Guest terminal create your mount point:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/shared_folder_name`

and then mount:

`sudo mount -t vboxsf Share /mnt/shared_folder_name`

You should then be able to navigate to /mnt/shared_folder_name and see the contents of the shared folder as anticipated.